# How to execute code once in the beginning of an Angular app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have a situation where I need to have a piece of code execute only once at the start of the angular app.  My app searches for a beacon using the **cordova-plugin** and if it finds one, the app is redirected to another state otherwise it stays on the `home/splash` state.

Currently I have this code running in the "home" controller and it is working but I was hoping for a more elegant solution. I am controlling the state change using a simple `if/else` statement and a variable on the `$scope`.

Here's my controller:

```
homeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$rootScope', '$ionicPlatform', '$cordovaBeacon'];
function homeCtrl($scope, $state, $rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaBeacon) {

    $scope.skip = false;        
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        $cordovaBeacon.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();

        $rootScope.$on("$cordovaBeacon:didRangeBeaconsInRegion", function(event, pluginResult) {
            if (!$scope.skip) {
                $scope.skip = true;
                $state.go('app.beacon');
            }
        });           

        $cordovaBeacon.startRangingBeaconsInRegion($cordovaBeacon.createBeaconRegion("abcdefg", "8484848484848484848"));
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: @Manu the document was ready long before the controller in your demo fires. Angular doesn't bootstrap before ready

Answer (score 1):

Use Run

```
app.run(function('$scope', '$state', '$rootScope', '$ionicPlatform', '$cordovaBeacon'){
function homeCtrl($scope, $state, $rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaBeacon) {

$scope.skip = false;        
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    $cordovaBeacon.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();

    $rootScope.$on("$cordovaBeacon:didRangeBeaconsInRegion", function(event, pluginResult) {
        if (!$scope.skip) {
            $scope.skip = true;
            $state.go('app.beacon');
        }
    });           

    $cordovaBeacon.startRangingBeaconsInRegion($cordovaBeacon.createBeaconRegion("abcdefg", "8484848484848484848"));
});
```

Run will be executed first before any controller is loaded or any service is injected.

Answer (score -1):

[ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) is something that you need in your case

Whereever you're defining your `app` or `controller` you can point the method that you want to execute at the beginning of your app **only once** in `ng-init` attribute.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="myText='Hello World!'">

<h1>{{myText}}</h1>

<p>The ng-init directive has created an AngularJS variable, which you can use in the application.</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[source](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-init)

---

**However, angular docs strictly states that you should not use `ngInit` for initializing purposes.** ([see docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit))

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into
>   your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such
>   as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo
>   below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these
>   few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize
>   values on a scope.

Initializing values is something that should be done from controller. [(see docs)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

> Use controllers to:
>
> Set up the initial state of the $scope object. Add behavior to the
>   $scope object.

Comment: this is not what `ng-init` is intended to be used for...docs are clear about that. Why would you need the view to manage this in the first place?